# Events while one loads and when it finishes loading vector layer in OpenLayers v6

Tags: openlayers, rendering, events

There was a code with OpenLayers v5, which showed a "loading" while loading a layer and the same (loading) was removed when the layer is already being shown on the map.
That's because I have several layers that take a while to render.

[CODE my_layer]

```
var my_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({        
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(207,125,18,1.0)',
            width: 3.5,
        })
    }),
    source:  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
        return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});
```

[CODE OpenLayers v5]

```
// show loading, while loading the layer
my_layer.on("precompose", function () {
   document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.add("loader");
});

//remove loading, after the layer is loaded
 my_layer.on("render", function () {
    document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.remove("loader");
 });
```

However, the same code does not work with OpenLayers v6. So I couldn't get an event to show the loading while loading the layer.
The two events below show when the layer is finished. Any idea?

[CODE OpenLayers v6]

```
// show loading, while loading the layer
my_layer.on("prerender", function () {
   document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.add("loader");
});

//remove loading, after the layer is loaded
 my_layer.on("postrender", function () {
    document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.remove("loader");
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `prerender` and `postrender` vector layer events  you have to use `featuresloadstart` and `featuresloadend` vector source events:

```
my_layer.getSource().on("featuresloadstart", function () {
   document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.add("loader");
});

my_layer.getSource().on("featuresloadend", function () {
  document.getElementById("my_loader").classList.remove("loader");
});
```